# ¿como evito que se esconda el contenido en las tab de ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic

Estoy intentando poner dentro de un pagina .html una tab con el siguiente codigo:

```
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
   <ion-content>
     <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-icon-only" delegate-handle="myhandle">
        <ion-tab title="A">
           <ion-content><h1>Home - A</h1></ion-content>
        </ion-tab><br />
        <ion-tab title="B">
           <ion-content>Home - B</ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
      </ion-tabs>
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Pero haciendo esto los contenidos de las tab se ponen debajo de las cabeceras de las tab y ademas queda un espacio en blanco arriba (El panel tab se queda abajo).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice ciertas cosas para que se muestre como quiero: Quitar la etiqueta ion-content y con estilo bajar los contenidos de las tab (Meti los estilos ahi, pero luego si no se puede hacer de otra forma paso los estilos a css).

```
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-icon-only" delegate-handle="myhandle">
    <ion-tab title="A" >
      <ion-content style="margin-top:100px;"><h1>Home - A</h1></ion-content>
    </ion-tab><br />
    <ion-tab title="B">
     <ion-content style="margin-top:100px;">Home - B</ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

**La pregunta es:** ¿Como puedo hacer que se muestre normal las tab dentro de la pagina .html con solo las etiquetas de ionic y sin acudir a agregar css?

Creo que de pronto me falta alguna etiqueta para evitar ese problema.

Comment: y el tabs-bar? y es puro Javascript? sin ningun otro framework?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" view-title="Browse">
```

tenes que agregar ese atributo en true

Comment: No, no funciono asi.